# Docker + NodeJS: node_modules not the same between docker-compose up and docker-compose run

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I am trying to dockerize a simple node js app for development purposes.
To do so I created a simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:15-alpine

# Code folder inside Docker
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code


# Install deps before mounting volume to improve caching
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# No need to copy code, we are building a volume later
EXPOSE 1234
```

As well as two (very similar) docker-compose.yml files, one for testing and the other for running the app in dev mode.

```yaml
version: "3.1"
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:4
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: my-user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-pswd
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: my-db

  app:
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    build: .
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"
    env_file: ./.docker.env
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /code/node_modules
```

The problem is that whenever i launch `docker-compose up`, `npm run dev` which is just pointing to `nodemon index.js` fails because the `nodemon` packaage is not installed.

Whenever i launch `docker-compose run app` it runs without any issues. As well as `docker-compose run app sh` which allows me to launch `npm run dev` without any issues.

Both `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.test.yml` have `NODE_ENV=development`, and the test file also launches a command from node_modules (`mocha` to be exact`).

Note that this behaviour appeared once i migrated from `node:15` to `node:15-alpine`.

I would be very grateful if anyone has any idea why.

Comment: Can you share your project structure - more specifically where your dockerfiles live in respect to the docker-compose files

Comment: @nishkaush my Dockerfile lives at the root of my project, as well as the docker-compose files

Comment: Your `volumes:` instruct Docker to preserve the `node_modules` tree the first time it's run and use that preserved volume in preference to what's in the image: all updates to `package.json` will be completely ignored.  If you're just trying to run Node against your local source tree, installing it locally might be an easier path.

Comment: I'm not posting an answer but the problem fixed itself (?).

After rebuilding the image a certain amount of times, it just worked. No diff on Dockerfile of docker-compose files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try mapping your `node_modules` like so:

```yaml
volumes:
  - .:/code
  - node_modules:/code/node_modules
```

Alternatively, try building again but first clearing your cache with:

```sh
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

then running `docker-compose up`

Comment: Thanks a lot @nishkaush! 
Sadly none of the solutions worked. I believe this is inherent to the way the alpine image works, since I did not have the problem with node:15(ubuntu)

But i can't explain why it works when i launch the container manually instead of with `docker-compose up`